# Java: Unit Test is not returning the correct result

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm writing a program in which if there aren't any reviews for a game then I need to add it to the map.  If there is a review for a game then add the given review to the corresponding GameInfo.  My code compiles fine, but my Unit Test aren't returning the points I need for them to return to show that my code is executing correctly.  Here is my code:

```
class GameInfoCollection {
    // TODO - you need to use a Map (from a String, the title, to a GameInfo) to keep track of all the GameInfo's
    Map<String, Integer> titles = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    // TODO - if there are no reviews for the game, create a new GameInfo  (with this review) and add it to the map
    // if there's one, add the given review to the corresponding GameInfo 
    public void addGameReview(String gameTitle, Review r)
    {
        if (titles.isEmpty()) {
            GameInfo g = new GameInfo("Review");
        } else titles.put(gameTitle, 1);

    }

    public int getNumberOfReviewsForGame(String gameTitle)
    {
        // TODO - implement this
        return titles.get(titles);
    }
```

Here is my Unit Test for these methods. It should return 20 points, but it isn't returning any points:

```
public void testGetNumberOfReviewsForGame()
    {       
        GameInfoCollection gic=new GameInfoCollection();


        gic.addGameReview("g1",new Review("cool",5));
        gic.addGameReview("g1",new Review("cool",3));
        gic.addGameReview("g2",new Review("cool",2));
        gic.addGameReview("g3",new Review("cool",2));

        Assert.assertEquals(2,gic.getNumberOfReviewsForGame("g1"));
        Assert.assertEquals(1,gic.getNumberOfReviewsForGame("g2"));
        gic.addGameReview("g1",new Review("cool",3));
        Assert.assertEquals(3,gic.getNumberOfReviewsForGame("g1"));
    }

    @Grade(points=20)
    @Test
```

Here is my code for my entire program.Please note that there are sections at the end which I haven't got to yet.

```
package assignment;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import java.util.*; // List, ArrayList, Map, HashMap

class Review {
    public String reviewText;
    public int numberOfStars;

    public Review(String reviewText, int numberOfStars) {
        this.reviewText=reviewText;
        this.numberOfStars=numberOfStars;
    }
}

class GameInfo {
    private String title;
    // need an ArrayList to keep the reviews;
    private Review[] reviews = new Review[10];
    int numReviews=0;

    public GameInfo(String title) {
        this.title=title;
        // you may want to initialize any other variables you create here
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    // TODO - adds the review to the 'array' of reviews. You need to keep all reviews in an array
    public void addReview(Review r) {
        reviews[numReviews] = r;
        ++numReviews;
    }

    // TODO - returns the number of reviews which have been added to this GameInfo
    public int getNumberOfReviews() {
        return numReviews;
    }

    // TODO - returns the sum of the number of stars which have been added to this GameInfo
    // you have to calculate this from your array
    public int getSumOfStars() {
        int sum=0;
        for (int i=0; i<numReviews;++i)
            sum +=reviews[i].numberOfStars;
        return sum;
    }

    // TODO - returns the average number of stars for this GameInfo's reviews
    // again, have to calculate this (or at least the sum of stars) from your array
    public double getAverageStarRating() {
        double firstNumber = getSumOfStars();
        double secondNumber = getNumberOfReviews();
        double avg = firstNumber/secondNumber;

        return avg;
    }
}

// TODO - you need to implement all these methods
class GameInfoCollection {
    // TODO - you need to use a Map (from a String, the title, to a GameInfo) to keep track of all the GameInfo's
    Map<String, Integer> titles = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    // TODO - if there are no reviews for the game, create a new GameInfo  (with this review) and add it to the map
    // if there's one, add the given review to the corresponding GameInfo 
    public void addGameReview(String gameTitle, Review r)
    {
        if (titles.isEmpty()) {
            GameInfo g = new GameInfo("Review");
        } else titles.put(gameTitle, 1);

    }

    public int getNumberOfReviewsForGame(String gameTitle)
    {
        // TODO - implement this
        return titles.get(titles);
    }
```

Please note that I'm still new to Java and any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As a start, HashMap is key->value collection (single key points to single value), it seems you want a key to multiple values or something similar, maybe a Multimap<String,GameInfo> (see Guava) or Map<String, Collection<GameInfo>>.

Comment: Please only include the relevant (but complete) code in your question.

Comment: @nbrooks I edited the question to only include relevant code

Comment: @AlexC Thanks, and what is Guava please?

Comment: *"// TODO - if there are no reviews for the game, create a new GameInfo  (with this review) and add it to the map"* You're not doing the latter ... why?

Comment: @Tom It I thought I was taking care of that with this, but I'm apparently not. 
else titles.put(gameTitle, 1);
Thanks

Comment: That is the `else` branch, but that TODO is talking about the `if` branch. You don't add your new GameInfo anywhere ... so what is the point in creating it?

Comment: @rls1982 https://github.com/google/guava but if you are not familiar with it you may want to stick with Map<String, Collection<GameInfo>>

Comment: @AlexC Thanks for sharing

Comment: @Tom This is where my naivete with Java is coming into play. I thought that the else branch would take care of it

Comment: No, if the `if` branch has been taken, then no other `else if` or `else` branch will be executed. They are all skipped, then.

Comment: @Tom okay I now see your point. Thanks

Comment: @Tom Like this:
if (titles.isEmpty()) {
      GameInfo g = new GameInfo("Review");
      g.addReview(r);
     } else titles.put(gameTitle, 1);

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework assignment, and I'm guessing the unit test is part of the code your teacher provided. The fact that the unit test is failing means, not that the unit test is wrong, but that your code is not behaving correctly. In particular, the parts in `GameInfoCollection` that you haven't finished.

So, let's go over what each of those TODO comments means:

```
// TODO - you need to use a Map (from a String, the title, to a GameInfo) to keep track of all the GameInfo's
```

A Map has keys and values, and is said to map from the keys to the values. In the declaration `Map<String, Integer>`, the first type (String) is the type of the keys, and the second is the type of the values. The TODO here is saying that the type of the values needs to be `GameInfo`.

```
// TODO - if there are no reviews for the game, create a new GameInfo  (with this review) and add it to the map
```

Every part of this needs to be done inside the `if` branch. You need to a) create a new `GameInfo`, b) put the review in it, and c) add it to the map. You are currently doing only part a), and even for that you aren't passing in the right value to the constructor - take a look at the `GameInfo` constructor and the name of the argument it takes; does "Review" match that?

```
// if there's one, add the given review to the corresponding GameInfo
```

This is about what should go in the `else` branch.

```
// TODO - implement this
```

Technically this method already has an implementation, but you're going to need to change it to correctly match the change from the first TODO about the map value type.